# Subtracting (Apache log) timestamp strings in python?

Tags: python, apache, logging, timestamp

I have an apache log which has timestamps like:

```
[03/Feb/2013:02:52:05 +0000]
```

As a string. for my purposes the trailing +0000 isn't needed. My end goal is to get the time-difference between two time stamps in minutes. Is there a more elegant, less verbose approach than just hacking up and comparing the elements in a piecemeal, ripple-adding fashion?

Ideally I'd like to do as little as possible to the string before using it to initialize a time object of some sort, which has a 'compare_to( )' type method.

I'm relatively new to python, so I'm sorry if there's an obvious library or approach for this, but I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the timezone offset, you can just use the datetime module to parse the data:

```
from datetime import datetime

line = '[03/Feb/2013:02:52:05 +0000]'
date = line[1:line.find(' ')]   #  take the string from the second character to the first blank
line_timestamp = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")

print repr(line_timestamp)
# datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 3, 2, 52, 5)
```

You can then just subtract the values.

Comment: and if I need the TZ, one has to use dateutil.parser.parse which does not like the 1st colon after the year.

Comment: `dateutil.parser.parse` is terribly slow, you can easily create tzinfo subclass and populate it with the offset `sign*(offset // 100 * 60 + offset % 100)` getting 13x speedup in my case.